# Trying to persist an object with an empty array in bookshelf.js

Tags: typescript, bookshelf.js

Well, I'm quite new with all this TS and trying to get this simple API working, I've defined some interfaces for my datatypes and sharing then between the client and the API itself.

But I'm hitting a wall when trying to store a User in DB using bookshelf.js to do it, just because I've defined a User-Projects relationship as an array of `IProject`'s in the `IUser`.

The `user.d.ts` I'm trying to store:

```
interface IUser {
    login: string
    pass: string
    name: string
    isAdmin: boolean
    projects?: IProject[]
}
```

And the way I'm doing it in the server is by sending an empty array, expecting TS + bookshelf to do the trick:

```
export function post(req, res){
    if (req.session.user && req.session.user.isAdmin) {
        let user: IUser = {
            login: req.body.login,
            pass: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.pass),
            name: req.body.name,
            isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
            projects: []
        }

        createUser(user).then(status => res.sendStatus(status), status => res.sendStatus(status))
```

Where `createUser()` essentially does:

```
User.forge(u).save().then(() => resolve(201), () => reject(500))
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting the 500 when POST-ing?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on why I'm getting the 500 when POST-ing?

500 indicates a server error (not a client error). This can however because the server crashed as the client sent something the server didn't handle properly.

You would need to look at the stack traces on the server. The code:

```
User.forge(u).save().then ...
```

indicates an issue with the `forge` OR `save` function (because of how promises work).

Comment: Yup, I agree. But as the request was rejected explicitly in code with the `reject(500)`, there's no crash in server and no stack trace to look at. The problem, then, seemed to be, that I had to initialize `projects` field to an empty array of `IProject` (because that's what bookshelf's [`forge`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-static-forge) function would expect). But that still does not work D: